# TextInput stops taking input after one keystroke - prohibiting continuous typing

Tags: react-native, input

I'm trying to create a text input, but whenever I type in the box, the cursor goes away after one keystroke and requires me to reclick the box.

This is how I set the state `const [text, setText] = useState('');`

This is my component

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Enter text here" 
    multiline={true} 
    maxLength={200} 
    onChangeText={(text: string): void => setText(text)} 
    value={specialRequest} 
    returnKeyType="done" 
    blurOnSubmit={true} 
/>
```

I have this same error of refreshing with my RNPickerSelect. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the changes of input to `text`, while display a different value `specialRequest`.

Try taking out the line `value={specialRequest}`, or change it to `defaultValue={specialRequest}`.